# How to check class of a clicked link

Tags: jquery

I have several links on my page and want to run a JQuery Script when a user clicked on it. Previously I've added a unique ID to the link, e.g.

```
<a id="user_1" class="mylink">
```

On my click event i then extracted the ID and started the processing on it

```
userid = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
```

Now I have the problem that my page might have several links with the same id, and of course that's not possible (afaik). So I think I have to add it as class, right? e.g.

```
<a class="mylink user_1">
```

Is this the best way? And how could I then extract the userID ('1') from the class? The jQuery-Script should of course also take care that there are some a-links without class 'user_,,,'.
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nicest way of doing this is with custom `data-*` attributes.  These comply to the HTML5 standard and work universally in browsers older than that standard.

So your link might look like this:

```
<a data-user="1" class="mylink">
```

Your click handler could then look like this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var userId = $(this).data('user');
});
```

This works because [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) imports `data-*` attributes.

If there is no `data-user` attribute set, `userId` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Brillant! I've read about this new feature implemented in jQuery 1.4.3 but I thought it was restricted to HTML5 only. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

`this.className` or if you want to do it using a jQuery object (there is no good reason to do so): `$(this).attr('className')`

From this string you could extract the ID with a regex (`/userid_([0-9]+)/`)...

---

However, using the HTML5 `data-` attributes would be better. Since browsers are very tolerant about unknown attributes they do not break anything and will work fine with HTML4 and XHTML:

```
<a class="mylink" data-userid="1">---</a>
...
var userid = $(this).data('userid');
```

The nice thing is: if you put valid JSON in a data attribute, `.data('yourAttr')` will automatically return an object instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/Wa6gN/

Comment: That's actually the code I have, but not a solution....? Even worser it's a step back, because this does not extract the ID from the name...